# How to create step definition in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cucumberjs

I was trying to create a step definition for the steps I added in my feature file.I have Cucumber Full Support installed in my VS Code.But still I am not able to create step definition.Could someone help me to solve this?

PFB the example code to make it more clear
 I have a feature file with two steps like

```
And event list has the following IDs 
  | offlineEventId |
  | 1              |
  | 2              |

And event list has the following IDS and desc
  | offlineId | offlineDescription  |
  | 1         | abc                 |
  | 2         | xyz                 |
```

And I have written step defns for both

```
this.Then(/^event list has the following offline IDs/, function(expectedEventTable){

});



this.Then(/^event list has the following offline event IDs and desc/, function(expectedEventTable) {

});


 But both the steps in feature file is pointing to the first method in step definition
```

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a few mistakes in your step definitions. First the name has to end with a $/ not just a /. Secondly your names don't match up with the names in the feature file. You have 'offline' in the names of you step definitions but 'offline' doesn't appear in you feature file. I don't know why you would get both steps running the same step definition my guess would be that there's an error somewhere in some code you haven't shared. So I have working the following feature file, Test.feature:

```
Feature: Test

Scenario: Test Cucumber is working
    Given I want it to work
    When I Run this feature
    Then I should see the right console log messages 
    And event list has the following IDs 
    | offlineEventId |
    | 1              |
    | 2              |
    And event list has the following IDS and desc
    | offlineId | offlineDescription  |
    | 1         | abc                 |
    | 2         | xyz                 |
```

and the steps are in a step definition file Test.steps.ts

```
module.exports = function () {

  this.Given(/^I want it to work$/, function(){
    console.log('Given step');
  });

  this.When(/^I Run this feature$/, function(){
    console.log('When step');
  });

  this.Then(/^I should see the right console log messages$/, function(){
    console.log('Then step 1');
  });

  this.Then(/^event list has the following IDs$/, function(expectedEventTable){
    console.log('Then step 2');
  });

  this.Then(/^event list has the following IDS and desc$/, function(expectedEventTable) {
    console.log('Then step 3');
  });
};
```

That gives the following output:

```
Feature: Test

  Scenario: Test Cucumber is working
Given step
  √ Given I want it to work
When step
  √ When I Run this feature
Then step 1
  √ Then I should see the right console log messages
Then step 2
  √ And event list has the following IDs
      | offlineEventId |
      | 1              |
      | 2              |
Then step 3
  √ And event list has the following IDS and desc
      | offlineId | offlineDescription |
      | 1         | abc                |
      | 2         | xyz                |

1 scenario (1 passed)
5 steps (5 passed)
```

Comment: I tried this also .But it is going to the first method written.Like,if step definition for second feature line is written first ,it will not take the proper one.Do they take in continuous order?Any steps to create step definition directly from feature file?

Comment: The steps should be pattern matching the complete string, so I don't know how your feature file is calling a step that doesn't match. The only thing I can think of is that maybe it's not the feature file actually calling the step that is actually running the step it just looks like it.

Comment: I don't know why is it behaving so in visual studio code.It was fine with intellij idea.I adjusted the code in step definition till it calls the correct step